# Ubuntu 16.02 lts error al instalar e desinstalar paquetes

Tags: linux

No puedo instalar ningun paquete programas nada ni desinstalar eso me sucede desde que instale mysql alguna ayudar xfavor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado haciendo lo que te dice el comando sudo? `apt-get -f update`

Comment: prueba `sudo apt --fix-broken install` a ver que dice

Answer (score 0):

Amigo intenta instalar aptitude con el comando sudo

> apt-get install aptitude

Luego abrelo escribiendo:

> sudo aptitude

Dentro de el presione **(shift + 7) = /** para hacer una busqueda y coloca mysql. ahi te deberian salir todo lo que necesitas selecionas con **+** y luego presiona **u** para poder instalar

eso que te comente es para poder instalar las dependencias de mysql-server, pues es lo que te molesta, si te quieres deshacer de el simplemente debes esrcibir estos comandos:

```
1. sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common 
2. sudo apt-get autoremov 
3. sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

Comentame como te va

Comment: Gracias pero como digo no puedo instalar ni desinstalar sale el mismo mensaje de la captura nisiquiera puede instlar apt-get install aptitude sale el mismo mensaje de la captura

Comment: ya probaste con desinstalar con el purge?

Comment: si purge, remove autoremove todas las posibles maneras de desinstalar y nada sale el mismo mensaje

Comment: uf que raro, hasta aqui llegan mis conocimientos, seguire investigando a ver que puede ser